# Unable to find css best_in_place with test helpers

Tags: capybara, ruby-on-rails-5, best-in-place

I am trying to get best in place's
[test helpers](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place#test-helpers)
working in my app. I am using

[Capybara with Test::Unit](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-testunit) 
I have written a test like this.

```
class CompaniesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include BestInPlace::TestHelpers

  def setup
    @company = companies(:public)
  end

  test "should have best in place fields on show" do
    get company_path(@company)
    assert_response :success
    assert_match @company.name, response.body
    bip_text( @company, :name, "new name" )
  end 
end
```

I am getting an error like this

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find css "#best_in_place_company_1001664029_name"
```

I tried adding a sleep(0.5) before bip_text to see if it is a timing issue this did not change the error.

EDIT:

```
<span data-bip-type="input"
 data-bip-attribute="name"  
 data-bip-object="company" 
 data-bip-original-content="Lightbulbs Corp." 
 data-bip-skip-blur="false" 
 data-bip-url="/companies/1001664029" 
 data-bip-value="Lightbulbs Corp." 
 class="best_in_place" 
 id="best_in_place_company_1001664029_name">Lightbulbs Corp.</span>
```

Here is what the css element for the page in the test env looks like. It looks like the id is correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's looking for an item with an id of best_in_place_company_1001664029_name but you say the element on the page has an id of best_in_place_company_47_name - so it's never going to find that.  What is the id of @company?

Comment: That is why is have (different_company) there. The one company in the test is from my fixtures. The one in the html is a seed in my development db viewed using my development server. In the rails console test env I can do Company.find(1001664029) and it returns the correct company so the id in the error is the one that should be found on the page.

Comment: Then you need to look at the page.html and see whats actually on it in the test environment.  Are you using database_cleaner? Do you have it set to truncation mode for tests using JS?  Have you set use_transactional_tests/use_transactional_fixtures to false?

Comment: I edited the html this is from the rails server in test env. looks like the id is correct. I am not familiar with the other possibilities I will do some searching. btw thanks for the help good to have some direction to go in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reread your question and noticed you're using `get`.  That's not a Capybara method and you can't mix the two different APIs and expect things to work.  To implement what you're doing using Capybara it would be something like

```
test "should have best in place fields on show" do
  visit company_path(@company)
  assert_text @company.name
  bip_text( @company, :name, "new name" )
end
```